# Audio conflict between applications when my audio interface is the default audio output

Tags: audio, mac, interface, applications

Sorry if this is not the correct place but... has anybody had audio problems when two different audio capable applications (let's say Google chrome and any DAW) are up, on a mac, when you have only one audio interface connected to the mac and configured as the default output for any application? Even If only one application is sending audio, as soon as you start a second audio capable application the first app starts to produce 5 seconds of audio artifacts every two or three minutes.

This problem does not occur when you don't use the audio interface, so my first bet was opening a ticket with the interface vendor (PreSonus) but after several months and dozens of emails still nothing.

My current workaround is to configure the internal speakers of the mac as the default audio output and only the application I do need to use the audio interface, my DAW, to use it.

It is not a perfect solution because I can not hear every audio source with the best quality but at least I don't have the audio problems.

I wonder is this an expected behavior or it is a real problem?, I don't want to buy another audio interface and then experience the same problem again.

Thank you for your patience and sorry for my english.

Comment: Sounds like a driver problem to me. Also check for consistent nip

Comment: Thank you. What is a nip?:)   Do you have a similar setup ( I mean a mac with an audio interface) ? and don't have any audio problem like this when you have two applications running?, just one  example I have the problem  with hearing a video in youtube and my DAW is up (the daw does not need to be playing any audio)

Comment: a nip? No idea. It's supposed to read "consistent sample rates" - meaning set the device to the same sample rate the DAW is using for the project. That can eliminate anything to do with the core audio sample rate converter. I have a similar setup, but not experiencing any of the issues that you are. Everything seems to work as expected. I have a $50 external USB interface driving a pair of digital speakers (Genelec) which seems to work fine. Gonna blame phone and autocorrect for the nip.

Comment: Is your DAW set to release ASIO [or equivalent] in the background? I've not seen it happen in quite some time, but ASIO used to 'hold too tight' onto the audio outs when it was running. Knowing your macOS version & DAW type & version might help, but I also think it's a driver issue & would take it to the makers of your DAW. [There's also the potential for Chrome to be the culprit - it often breaks the mac toolbox guidelines - but I don't use it enough to be aware of anything specific]